# How to make use of Slack Web API?

Tags: python-2.7, httprequest, slack-api, slack

I want to use the provided slack web API https://api.slack.com/web#basics to get some messages out of a channel. I looked at https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.history & used the Request API to call the service.

```
payload = {'token': 'XXXXXXXXXXXX', 'channel': '#scanbot' , 'count' : '10'}
r = requests.get('https://slack.com/api/channels.history', params=payload)
print r.status_code
print r.text
```

But i am getting the error:

```
200
{"ok":false,"error":"channel_not_found"}
```

I am pretty sure the channel exists and I am providing correct API key. Can someone point me at the correct directions please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the channel ID as the argument to the [`channels.history` endpoint](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.history).

The channel IDs may be fetched by checking the [`channels.list` endpoint](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.list).

See for example the [source of the Slacker package](https://github.com/os/slacker/blob/master/slacker/__init__.py).

The JSON-formatted response may be parsed with:

```
import json
data = json.loads(r.text)
print data
```

Comment: okay,, how do i pretty print the json response that i received in `r.text`